# Selecting joined distinct/last

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

Ok, i have two tables, like this:

```
Person:
| ID | Name |
+----+------+
| 0  | Carl |
+----+------+
| 1  | Max  |
+----+------+
| 2  | Lars |

Status
| PersonID | Submitted  | Status |
+----------+------------+--------+
| 0        | *DATETIME* | 1      |
+----------+------------+--------+
| 0        | *DATETIME* | 1      |
+----------+------------+--------+
| 0        | *DATETIME* | 3      |
+----------+------------+--------+
| 0        | *DATETIME* | 1      |
+----------+------------+--------+
| 1        | *DATETIME* | 5      |
+----------+------------+--------+
```

What i want to recive is to get all persons in the user table among with the last submitted status.

If i use something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Person.Name As Username,
    Status.Status As Userstatus
FROM Person
LEFT JOIN Status
ON Status.PersonID = Person.ID
```

I get a result like this:

```
| Username | Userstatus |
+----------+------------+
| Carl     | 1          |
+----------+------------+
| Carl     | 3          |
+----------+------------+
| Max      | 5          |
+----------+------------+
| Lars     | NULL       |
+----------+------------+
```

So, how can i do this? In this case, lets say that the latest Status.Submitted is ==1 (Last row for Status.PersonID where PersonID == 0), skip the other Carls.

EDIT: I forgot to write that I'm using SQL Compact.

Edit2: Got some awesome answers, unfortunate i forgot to mention that i also want to get users with null status values. I there fore added a new user to the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the aggregate function `max` in combination with a group by statement.

```
SELECT
    person.Name As Username,
    s3.status As Userstatus
FROM person
LEFT JOIN (
  select s.person_id, s.status 
  from status s
  join (select max(submitted) as last,person_id
       from status group by person_id) s2
  on s.person_id = s2.person_id
  where s.submitted = s2.last) s3
ON person.id = s3.person_id;
```

**Sql Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9822b/19

Comment: Yea, but that gives me the highest status, right? This would be bad in this case since I want the last added (the current). The current status may be a "3" and if the user once had "5" before and it will show "5"..?

Comment: @gubbfett Exellent!  Glad I could help someone this morning.

Answer (score 1):

Try this **`Query`**:

```
SELECT
    Person.Name As Username,
    Status.Status As Userstatus
FROM Person
INNER JOIN Status
ON Status.PersonID = Person.ID
WHERE Status.Submitted in 
(Select Max(Submitted) from Status group by PersonID)
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks! Works awesome and is exactly what i asked for. Since i'm stupid i forgot to mention that i would also like to recieve ALL users with a null value if they don't have a status... How can i achieve that?

Comment: What happen if a different user having a sumbitted date which is another user's max(submitted) date?

Comment: @Kaf thats the Logic, Op wants to get **`latest`** status

Comment: [Have a look at here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/24426/1), this is your query results. Carl having a status on the same day when Max has his latest status.

Comment: @Kaf Please change the data type to **`DATETIME`** Also logically at the **`same date and time`**, a **person can't have 2 different status**

Comment: Okay, For demo purpose [date] is fine (agree OP has datetime). **Same user does not have two different statuses at the same date/datetime.** Please check fiddle data, user 0 has a status on the same date when user 1 having his max(submitted) date.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't got compact edition but I think this should work:

[SQL-SERVER 2008 EXAMPLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8049f/13)

```
select person.name as username,
       x.status as userstatus
from person left join (
      select s.personId, s.status
      from status s join (
        select personId, max(submitted) subs
        from status
        group by personid ) s2
        on s.personid = s2.personid and s.submitted = s2.subs
      ) x on person.id = x.personid

| USERNAME | USERSTATUS |
-------------------------
|     Carl |          1 |
|      Max |          5 |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    Person.Name As Username,
    Status.Status As Userstatus
FROM Person
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP(1)
        *
    FROM Status
    WHERE Status.PersonID = Person.ID
    ORDER BY Status.Submitted DESC
) AS [Status]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out -

```
SELECT Username,Userstatus<br>
FROM
(
    SELECT
    Person.Name As Username,
    Status.Status As Userstatus,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Status.PersonID ORDER BY Status.Submitted DESC) AS RN,
FROM Person
LEFT JOIN Status
ON Status.PersonID = Person.ID
)
WHERE rn=1
```